# How to update to QGIS 2.0.1 on Mac?

Tags: qgis, mac, geos, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade to the newest version of qGIS but get the following error message when I open the installer:

```
QGIS requires the GEOS framework version 3.4 or newer.
```

I've had no luck maintaining my version of geos via the geos download page, and have instead installed it via homebrew.  Is it possible to tell qGIS where the homebrew maintained version of GEOS lives?

I would maintain osgeo via https://libgeos.org/ but keep getting error messages when I run the newest installer (3.4.2) and all advice [I've found elsewhere on debugging the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124983/errors-when-trying-to-install-geos-3-3-8-on-mac-osx) suggest that I shouldn't bother messing around w/ all the dependencies and should instead use homebrew.

So this brings me back to where I started: is it possible to have homebrew maintain a version of osgeo that qgis can continue to locate?  Or, am I forced to keep trying to debug the geos installer?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @NathanW: "homebrew" suggests macos.

Comment: I'm running 10.8.5

Comment: @James: Have you found an answer to this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @MorganHerlocker: fixed it by uninstalling everything and reinstalling via kyngchaos.  Essentially, forced me to take more care of how I maintain my dependencies by building again from the ground up.  Homebrew has it's place, but it's a bad way to maintain qGIS dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to upgrade is to use the binaries at http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: I have all the binaries that are maintained by kyngchaos (just reinstalled them to be sure).  It's GEOS framework that the qGIS installer tells me I don't have, and when intalling from the GEOS site installer, I get the following error message `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libgeos.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2`  Since I have successfully downloaded geos via homebrew, I was hoping I might be able to move the hb-version to wherever qgis looks for it

Comment: perhaps a bad idea, perhaps not.  i'm still trying to figure out best practices when it comes to maintaining packages for GIS apps.